# Informatica command task: double quotes in sed

Tags: sed, informatica

I need to run a `sed` command via command through `Informatica`. I already know that Informatica executes commands via `sh -c "{command}"`. However for my case, I need sed to replace a particular string such as `sed -i 's,xsi:namespace="http://url.example.com",,' file.xml`.

I have tried escaping the double-quotes with `\` but no dice, even thought it works when I do it directly in Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is really tricky.  One version that seems to work uses triple backslashes:

```
$ bash -c "sed 's,xsi:namespace=\\\"http://url.example.com\\\",,'" \
> <<< 'abc-xsi:namespace="http://url.example.com"-def'
abc--def
$
```

The first pair represent a backslash in the `-c` script; the backslash-quote represents a double quote in the `-c` script.  You can add `printf "%s\n"` before the `bash` to see the arguments passed to `bash`:

```
$ printf "%s\n" bash -c "sed 's,xsi:namespace=\\\"http://url.example.com\\\",,'" \
> <<< 'abc-xsi:namespace="http://url.example.com"-def'
bash
-c
sed 's,xsi:namespace=\"http://url.example.com\",,'
$
```

However, a little cogitation and experimentation shows that single backslashes are sufficient:

```
$ printf "%s\n" bash -c "sed 's,xsi:namespace=\"http://url.example.com\",,'" <<< 'abc-xsi:namespace="http://url.example.com"-def'
bash
-c
sed 's,xsi:namespace="http://url.example.com",,'
$ bash -c "sed 's,xsi:namespace=\"http://url.example.com\",,'" <<< 'abc-xsi:namespace="http://url.example.com"-def'
abc--def
$
```

However, it's hard to see how you didn't try this when you tried single backslashes.

Note that double backslashes are not the answer:

```
$ bash -c "sed 's,xsi:namespace=\\"http://url.example.com\\",,'" <<< 'abc-xsi:namespace="http://url.example.com"-def'
sed: 1: "s,xsi:namespace=\http:/ ...": unterminated substitute in regular expression
$ printf "%s\n" bash -c "sed 's,xsi:namespace=\\"http://url.example.com\\",,'" <<< 'abc-xsi:namespace="http://url.example.com"-def'
bash
-c
sed 's,xsi:namespace=\http://url.example.com\,,'
$
```

Another alternative, well worth thinking about (and it's basically what [haifzhan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1735756/haifzhan) suggests in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36210595)), is to put the `sed` script — or the whole `sed` command — into a script that you run.  This avoids questions of 'how many backslashes':

```
$ cat script.sed
s,xsi:namespace="http://url.example.com",,
$ sed -f script.sed <<<'abc-xsi:namespace="http://url.example.com"-def'
abc--def
$ bash -c "sed -f script.sed" <<<'abc-xsi:namespace="http://url.example.com"-def'
abc--def
$
```

The downside may be problems getting `script.sed` created and/or cleaned up.

Comment: I had to use the script route. Informatica was just not cooperating and no one else in other forums has gotten it to work either.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for [Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36210278/informatica-command-task-double-quotes-in-sed#comment60054767_36210595). I tested the command on Mac. See Jonathan's comments for more information.

Try this, it works for me

```
#!/bin/bash
sed -i '' -e  's,xsi:namespace="http://url.example.com",,' $1
```

Here's my test and output:

```
$ cat file.xml
xsi:namespace="http://url.example.com" hello there

$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash
sed -i '' -e  's,xsi:namespace="http://url.example.com",,' $1

$ ./test.sh file.xml      

$ cat file.xml
 hello there
```

Comment: Are you running on a Mac (or BSD)?  Your use of `sed -i '' …` suggests that you are.  The GNU `sed` uses just `-i` (no extra argument) to achieve the effect (no backup) that Mac `sed` achieves with `-i ''`.  The only portable notation specifies a non-empty backup suffix and attaches it to the `-i` option: `-i.bak`.